# Nested JSON dynamic data conversion to xls or csv file

Tags: java, json, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a JSON file which i need to convert it into excel or csv file .

JSON file:

```
 {

  "gstin": "37AAACGJSJOSFF",
  "fp": "032018",
  "b2b": [
    {
      "ctin": "33ASADKSDMK",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 500,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt\n": 5,
                "txval": 0,
                "iamt": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 87004,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "31-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "Y",
          "inum": "S78",
          "chksum": "13e230e9ednaskdjslsd23ea83a50cafbf675a111b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "37ADJKSKSF';DF",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 3092.64,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 34362.7,
                "camt": 3092.64
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 40548,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "05-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "200/AASDS/IKJO/RSJ",
          "chksum": "66395159aac02dfe3dfadkjasdlkbbafde86c9e27aa0fb1605ebbe"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 68429.97,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 760332.99,
                "camt": 68429.97
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 897193,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "03-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "235/HSLFA/IASDKC/DSKF",
          "chksum": "8b60e669ee6156e0ajhaf42e4189aabbb57245127c4e609d8e"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 84846.74,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 942741.6,
                "camt": 84846.74
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 1114535,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "03-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "236/HNSsdkfs/IsdkdC/Vsdkj",
          "chksum": "eb5110c0047adsdsd63cfedc686e3e84c9a5d9c126cb96d99645"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 348.13,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 8312.57,
                "camt": 648.13
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 452609,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "03-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "237/HNSdf/Isdxf/Rdf",
          "chksum": "8181aa8d52d4c9d58csdsf915e0f4955e48c59f57f21d799f51e117c6"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 68429.97,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 760333,
                "camt": 68429.97
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 897193,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "31-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "269/HNSSA/IsfsfC/Kdf",
          "chksum": "2a46181337bdgdg88cbdfec8f3322718f029fd9d8d96e3481"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 94438.83,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 1049320.3,
                "camt": 94438.83
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 1238198,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "31-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "271/HNSSA/Isfsf/Vada",
          "chksum": "be96bd7d39b4773e599dd5sfsf1b0cad152092777271590a76f8dcb6f"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 37297.41,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 414415.71,
                "camt": 37297.41
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 489011,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "31-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "272/HNSSA/Isdfs/RsfJ",
          "chksum": "684604977sdfsf304sfdsf12e3d82bee08705b675d5ccacad546"
        },
        {
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "csamt": 0,
                "samt": 283.99,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 3155.42,
                "camt": 283.99
              }
            }
          ],
          "val": 3723,
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "37",
          "idt": "03-03-2018",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "286/HsfdS/Isfs/Kadd",
          "chksum": "ef28779994414cf8sfsf7797bff799b5c9dda1f29a21cdb89112f2a843"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

output as :
[image]

My approch:

I used simple json jar to parse the data and tried writing the values by considering three cases JSON Object or JSON array or a String by which i was writing into a csv file column wise the problem i faced was the data is dynamic so in b2b data in first object under inv under itms under itms_det there are only four rows but in second object i have 5 rows, so in my output if you observe in first row there is no value under b2b__inv__itms__itm_det__samt that is because the first object doesn't have that field so i am facing a problem for generating header of the csv file and placing them accordingly.Is there any alternative way to do it not in java any other is also ok, any suggestions or help are welcome.

my code:

```
package json2csvdynamic;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.json.CDL;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

/**
 *
 * @author 00511175
 */
public class Json2csvdynamic {

    HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();
    HSSFRow row;
    int i;
    public int col;

    public HSSFRow getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(HSSFRow row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void excelproccessing(ArrayList arr, HSSFSheet sheet, String prev_key) {

        if (col < 20) {
            int j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
//            if (col != 0) {
//                jsexcel.row = jsexcel.sheet.getRow(0);
//                jsexcel.row = jsexcel.sheet.getRow(1);
//            }
                row = sheet.getRow(j);
                if (row == null) {
                    sheet.createRow(j);
                    row = sheet.getRow(j);
                }

                if (i == 0) {
                    if (prev_key.equalsIgnoreCase("") || prev_key.equals(null)) {
                        row.createCell(col).setCellValue((String) arr.get(i));
                    } else {
                        row.createCell(col).setCellValue(prev_key);
                    }

                } else {
                    row.createCell(col).setCellValue((String) arr.get(i));
                }
                j++;

            }
            col = col + 1;
//        System.out.println("a::" + a);

        }
    }

    public void arrayexcelprocessing(org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonarr, HSSFSheet sheet, String prev_key) {
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < jsonarr.size(); i++) {

//            row = sheet.getRow(j);
//            if (row == null) {
//                sheet.createRow(j);
//                row = sheet.getRow(j);
//            }
////            row.createCell(col).setCellValue(jsonarr.get(i).toString());
//            j++;
            org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) jsonarr.get(i);
            for (Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keySet().iterator();
                    iterator.hasNext();) {
                String key = (String) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("the level2 keys" + key);
                Object obj = jsonObject.get(key);
                if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
                    org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonarr1 = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) obj;

                    arrayexcelprocessing(jsonarr1, sheet, prev_key.concat("/").concat(key));

                } else if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
                    for (iterator = ((org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj).keySet().iterator();
                            iterator.hasNext();) {
                        String key1 = (String) iterator.next();
                        Object obj1 = ((org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj).get(key1);
                        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                        //   String FileName = "json.csv";
                        arr.add(key1);

                        arr.add(String.valueOf(obj1));
                        if (col < 20) {
                            excelproccessing(arr, sheet, prev_key.concat("/").concat(key1));
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("obj" + obj.toString());

                } else {
                    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                    //   String FileName = "json.csv";
                    arr.add(key);
                    arr.add(String.valueOf(obj));
                    if (col < 20) {
                        excelproccessing(arr, sheet, prev_key.concat("/").concat(key));
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        Json2csvdynamic jsexcel = new Json2csvdynamic();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\workspace\\json2csv\\test.json"));
        for (Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keySet().iterator();
                iterator.hasNext();) {

            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("the level1 keys" + key);
            Object obj = jsonObject.get(key);

            if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
                org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonarr = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) obj;

                jsexcel.arrayexcelprocessing(jsonarr, jsexcel.sheet, key);

            } else if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {

                org.json.simple.JSONObject jo = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;
            } else {

                ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                //   String FileName = "json.csv";
                arr.add(key);
                arr.add((String) obj);

                jsexcel.excelproccessing(arr, jsexcel.sheet, "");

            }

        }
        FileOutputStream out
                = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\workspace\\json2csv\\test.xls"));

        jsexcel.workBook.write(out);

        out.close();
    }

}
```